# How can I use ajax to submit h:selectOneRadio?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, radio-button

I'm having a problem getting things to work the way I think they should. I have a dataTable that I'm building from a list of benefits objects. Each of those objects can have one and only one type: group, account, or parent. I want to refresh the list when a radio button is selected. When the page loads, the group objects are displayed and the group radio button is pre-selected. If the user clicks the account radio button, I'm using Ajax to refresh the list, this time presenting Account objects. Here's the stripped down code:
XHTML:

```
<!-- Radio button to subset records  -->
<h:selectOneRadio
    id="varButtons"
    value="#{benefitUI.buttonValue}"
    styleClass="radio">
    <f:selectItem
        itemLabel="Group"
        itemValue="G" />
    <f:selectItem
        itemLabel="Account"
        itemValue="A" />
    <f:selectItem
        itemLabel="Parent"
        itemValue="P" />
    <p:ajax event="click" update="benList" process="@this"  />
</h:selectOneRadio>
<p:dataTable
    id="benList"        
    var="ben"
    value="#{benefitUI.filteredBenefitList}"
    rowIndexVar="vbRowIndex"
    rowClasses="panel-grid-row-odd, panel-grid-row-even"
    styleClass="mimic-datatable"

    <p:column headerText="From" style="text-align:center;">
        <h:outputText value="#{ben.beginDate}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="To" style="text-align:center;">
        <h:outputText value="#{ben.endDate}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Java for BenefitUI:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    /* Code that creates my unfiltered list removed for brevity. */
    /** benefitList is the name of the unfiltered list **/
    // Pre-select group on page load
    setButtonValue("G");
}

public List<Benefit> getFilteredBenefitList() {
    String filter = getButtonValue();

    List<Benefit> filteredList = new ArrayList<Benefit>();
    for (Benefit vb : benefitList) {
        // The below code is working just fine, when filter is not blank
        if ((filter.equals("G") & vb.getGroup() != null)
                || (filter.equals("A") & vb.getAccount() != null)
                || (filter.equals("P") & vb.getParent() != null)) {
            filteredList.add(vb);
        }
    }

    return filteredList;
}

public void setButtonValue(String bValue) {
    this.buttonValue = bValue;
}

public String getButtonValue() {
    return this.buttonValue();
}
```

The page loads just fine, displaying the group benefits. But when I click the Account button, an empty string is passed to the setButtonValue method, so when the filtered list is built, no records are included, and the page displays an empty list. What am I doing wrong that the itemValue isn't being sent to setButtonValue? Secondarily, why are the setButtonValue and the getFilteredBenefitList methods both being called four times?

I'm sure there's a keyword or something I'm missing, either on the Ajax line or in the selectItem, but I have no idea what it might be.

Comment: I'm willing to. What's the difference?

Comment: When I change to p:selectOneRadio, the setButtonValue method isn't called and the list doesn't refresh. I've found other forum posts complaining of the same behavior